# Mix of AngularJS and Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I have a page in which based on the one drop down value few more input fields are added. This page is driven by angularjs. Only for inducing additional input fields i have used jquery like this.

Html:

```
<label for="Type">MyDataType:</label> 
            <select ng-model="myData.Type" id="selectBox" >
                <option value="UL">Other</option>
                <option value="AUL">Auto</option>
            </select> 
            <div id="outputArea"> 



$("#selectBox").change(function() {
         var htmlString = "";
         var len = $(this).val();
         if (len == 'AUL'){
             htmlString = "<label for=\"Auto#\">Auto#:</label><input type=\"text\"ng-model=\"mydata.autoNum\">";
         }
    })
```

But angular is not able to recognize this `ng-model` When i do a `console.log($scope.myData.autoNum);` it will tell undefined. Please suggest me on this.

If `AUL` value is selected i need to include `mydata.autoNum` input field. And if user selects UL then mydata.autoNum should not display.

Comment: You would need to use `$compile` when injecting the html that has directives in it. But why are you using jQuery for this at all? It is very simply done in angular template and there is no need for the jQuery shown. Provide your template structure for more details

Comment: i tried to figure out to fit this in angular but i failed. Could you please give me some more information like how to do in angular when i wanted to include few more fields to the existing html

Comment: Can use `ng-if`. Need more code context to be able to help more

Comment: Please don't dump code blobs into comments. Update the question with formatted code and other relevant details

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you start by using `ng-if` in the template. The following uses the same conditional as in your jQuery change event

```
<span ng-if="myData.Type=='AUL'">
    <label for="Auto">Auto#:</label>
    <input id="Auto" type="text" ng-model="mydata.autoNum">
</span>
```

Comment: Thanks!! This works!! But if i select the drop down value as AUL and Enter the data in this `Auto#` field and later change the drop down value to something else this still holds the value of `mydata.autoNum`  and when i press a submit this value gets passed to back end also!

Comment: Then use a watch in controller to watch `myData.Type` and delete the `autoNum` property if value not right, or do some cleanup before submitting. Your jQuery would have had same problem if you made it work

Comment: So if `myData.Type != 'AUL'` then i will clear the value of `autoNum`.

Answer (score 0):

Jquery free example. I created a plunker example for you.
http://plnkr.co/edit/fIxF1yGMN2PFnuIl6S4c?p=preview

```
var app = angular.module('demo', []);

app.controller('demo', function($scope) {
    $scope.val;

    $scope.$watch('val', function(newVal) {
      console.log(newVal);
    })
});
```

And the template for that is

```
<div ng-controller="demo">
  <select ng-model="val" id="selectBox">
      <option value="UL">Other</option>
      <option value="AUL">Auto</option>
  </select>


  <br>
  <br>
  <div ng-if="val === 'AUL'">
    show only if val === AUL 
  </div>
</div>
```